# Selectpicker - Option clickable, but not selectable

Tags: javascript, select

I have a selectpicker with different options.I want that the options above the data-divider are selectable, bu the options below the data divider, should be clickable, but they should not be selectable as option. Any ideas how to solve that?

```
<select  class="selectpicker" >   
                <option value="view1">View 1</option>   
                <option value="view2">View 2</option>   
                <option data-divider="true"></option>   
                <option>Edit Views</option>   
             </select>
```

I tried to use the `disabled`  attribute, but this makes the option not clickable anymore.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "selectpicker" in javascript, and even not in DOM. That is just a class name like any other. And when using your code, all the options (including the divider. That also is not an HTML/Dom/Javascript thing) are equally selectable.  Oh, I know what happens. You are certainly using a library that does thing behind the curtain to "options" when they belong to a "select" that has "selectpicker" as class, and has a "data-divider" attribute to "true". But you haven't mentioned any library. And the tag of your question say nothing about that.

Comment: Note that that library may seem obvious to you. It may even really be. I am an old school JS amateur coder, and I never managed to learn a proper "library/platform" other than pure html/css/js (and I don't regret it, because if I managed to each time I had the intention to, 90% of the library I'd have learned would have been out of fashion for now). So may be all other contributer of this site see how obvious it is that you are talking about "reactJs" or "JQuery-UI" or whatever other thing I've never learned. But even if it were obvious, that deserved to be said and tagged as such.